# pushing back a commit to Github

Tags: github, push, commit

I have forked a repository on github, then cloned it (cloned the master repo) created a new branch worked on some files and then added and committed the changes. I pushed the changes to my forked repo via

`git push "my-remote" "my-branch"`

Now, I realize I made unnecessary changes and would like to only commit one change for a pull request to the `master`. Is there a way to reset the commits ?

Reading the help, I should be using `git reset --hard HEAD` but I am not sure of the meaning of `HEAD`

Answer (score 2):

HEAD points to the latest commit you made its like a pointer. Type `git log` and you shall find all your commits. So each time you use

`git reset --hard HEAD`

Your changes are pushed one commit back. Beware that using --hard means the commit changes that you are trying to revert back will be forever lost that way.

Comment: My commits are the latest, but I also found commits made by contributors .. I want to be sure that I am doing this right. `git reset --hard HEAD will remove the latest commit on date, right ?

Comment: @MeriemBen that is correct, but i would urge you to find a non-destructive method (there is one - just can't remember now), so in case you want to go "forward" again you will be able to do so

Comment: I believe you mean "revert" instead of "reset". I reverted the commits I made via git revert <hash-commit> then changed to another branch and used git cherry-pick <hash-commit> to select only one commit to push. Thanks for the help.

Comment: yup exactly that. Good job